# Discount on container line item type

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I've got a custom Cart Line Item Controller which basically bundles multiple products into 1 "container line item type". This is all working, but when I'm adding a discount to the cart the actual discount isn't applied. When there's a single product in the cart it's working, but when there's only a bundle in the cart it isn't.

This is the addLineItems function:

```php
public function addLineItems(Cart $cart, RequestDataBag $requestDataBag, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
    {
        $lineItems = $requestDataBag->get('lineItems');
        $lineItemsData = $lineItems->all();
        $totalItems = count($lineItemsData);

        if ($totalItems > 1) {
            $containerLineItemId = Uuid::randomHex();
            $containerLineItem = new LineItem($containerLineItemId, LineItem::CONTAINER_LINE_ITEM, $containerLineItemId, 1);

            // Make the lineItem stackable
            $containerLineItem->setStackable(true);

            // Make the lineItem removable
            $containerLineItem->setRemovable(true);


            $lineItemsArray = [];
            $engravementText = '';
            foreach ($lineItems as $id => $lineItemBag) {
                if ($lineItemBag instanceof RequestDataBag) {

                    $productId = $lineItemBag->get('id');
                    $engravementFont = $lineItemBag->get('engravementFont', null);
                    $engravementText = $lineItemBag->get('engravementText', null);
                    $giftCardTo = $lineItemBag->get('giftCardTo', null); // Check if giftCardTo exists
                    $giftCardFrom = $lineItemBag->get('giftCardFrom', null); // Check if giftCardFrom exists
                    $giftCardMessage = $lineItemBag->get('giftCardMessage', null); // Check if giftCardMessage exists
                    $lineItem = $this->getLineItem($productId);
                    $lineItem->setId(Uuid::randomHex());
                    // If engravementFont, engravementText and giftCardTo exist, add them to the payload
                    $payload = [];
                    if ($engravementFont !== null && $engravementText !== null) {
                        $payload['engravementFont'] = $engravementFont;
                        $payload['engravementText'] = $engravementText;
                    }

                    if ($giftCardTo !== null) {
                        $payload['giftCardTo'] = $giftCardTo;
                        $payload['giftCardFrom'] = $giftCardFrom;
                        $payload['giftCardMessage'] = $giftCardMessage;
                    }

                    if (!empty($payload)) {
                        $lineItem->setPayload($payload);
                    }

                    $lineItemsArray[] = $lineItem;

                }
            }

            $nestedLineItems = new LineItemCollection($lineItemsArray);

            $containerLineItem->setChildren($nestedLineItems);
            $containerLineItem->setPayload(['timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);

            // Set the label
            $containerLineItem->setLabel('Bundle');

            $cart = $this->cartService->getCart($context->getToken(), $context);
            $cart->add($containerLineItem);

            $this->cartPersister->save($cart, $context);
        } else {
            $count = 0;

            try {
                $items = [];
                /** @var RequestDataBag $lineItemData */
                foreach ($lineItems as $lineItemData) {

                    $lineItem = new LineItem(
                        $lineItemData->getAlnum('id'),
                        $lineItemData->getAlnum('type'),
                        $lineItemData->get('referencedId'),
                        $lineItemData->getInt('quantity', 1)
                    );


                    $lineItem->setStackable($lineItemData->getBoolean('stackable', true));
                    $lineItem->setRemovable($lineItemData->getBoolean('removable', true));
                    $lineItem->setPayload(['timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
                    $count += $lineItem->getQuantity();

                    $items[] = $lineItem;
                }
                $cart = $this->cartService->add($cart, $items, $context);

                if (!$this->traceErrors($cart)) {
//                    $this->addFlash(self::SUCCESS, $this->trans('checkout.addToCartSuccess', ['%count%' => $count]));
                }
            } catch (ProductNotFoundException $exception) {
                $this->addFlash(self::DANGER, $this->trans('error.addToCartError'));
            }
        }

        return $this->createActionResponse($request);

    }
```

When diving into the Core I found the CartScopeDiscountPackager class. In the getMatchingItems function I saw this part:

```php
$allItems = $cart->getLineItems()->filter(function (LineItem $lineItem) {
            return $lineItem->getType() === LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE && $lineItem->isStackable();
        });
```

So probably the discount is some kind of blocked and only applicable on PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE. But if I add CONTAINER_LINE_ITEM, it's still not working.

Anyone has an idea how I can also apply discount on the bundles?